# Rspec - Rails - How to follow a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, web-testing

Does anyone know how to make rspec follow a redirect (in a controller spec)? (e.g test/unit has follow_redirect!)

I have tried "follow_redirect!" and "follow_redirect" but only get

```
undefined method `follow_redirect!' for #<Spec::Rails::Example::ControllerExampleGroup::Subclass_1:0xb6df5294>
```

For example:
When I create an account the page is redirected to accounts page and my new account should be at the top of the list.

```
it "should create an account" do
  post :create, :name => "My New Account"
  FOLLOW_REDIRECT!
  response.code.should == "200"
  accounts = assigns[:accounts]
  accounts[0].name.should == "My New Account"
end
```

But FOLLOW_REDIRECT! needs to be changed to something that actually works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to test the redirect you are moving outside of the rspec-rails domain.

You can use Webrat or some other integration-test framework to test this.

The easiest way to solve this without resorting to integration testing is probably to mock out the method that is causing the redirect.

Comment: i think this answer is incorrect, the one from zetetic is correct

Comment: Actually this answer *is* correct, and mine is not. My answer only shows how to verify that a redirect occurs -- OP asked how to test the contents of the response after the redirect is followed.

Answer (score 68):

I think this is the default behavior for [rspec-rails](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec-rails/1.2.7.1/) controller tests, in the sense that you can set an expectation on the response status and/or path, and test for success.

For example:

```
it "should create an account" do
  post :create
  response.code.should == "302"
  response.should redirect_to(accounts_path)
end
```

Comment: Hi Zetetic. Thanks for your reply. What you describe in your answer would be the correct way to Verify that the response is a 302-redirect to the accounts_path. What I want to do is to follow the redirect to the accounts_path and verify the behaviour of that page. E.g. verify that my new account is listed there.

Comment: I updated my question, hope you don't mind that I borrowed your example.

Comment: Guess I misunderstood the question. Would `integrate_views` help in this situation?

Comment: `integrate_views` does not seem to help. I still get "...You are being redirected..." response, but it was a good try

Comment: Now I can test that the redirect worked. But that is not that I am looking for. I want, that rspec is following automatically the redirects and and I want to have success/error from the redirected page. This is important if you test a controller which enforces https. In that case I am even not leaving my domain. Any thought how to do that?

Comment: This answer addresses that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2874007/17410. Capybara is a good choice.

Comment: As of RSpec3.1, it prefers this syntax: `expect(response).to redirect_to(accounts_path)` see also - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher

Answer (score 35):

You can access the redirect location with

```
response.headers['Location']
```

you could then request that directly.

Comment: This is the only direct answer to the OP.  Others state what **should** be done, but this is the only one that tells how to do what is requested.  That is helpful in case someone comes here from a Google query like I did.

Comment: This would work but be sure to declare `response.params` if any.
For example, maybe I want to test that my redirect renders a particular flash message.  testing a `GET response.headers['Location']` alone won't do that.

Answer (score 5):

The spec is out of scope, if you want to follow a redirect use request spec, the equivalent of integration test in Test::Unit.

In request specs `follow_redirect!` works as well as in Test::Unit.

Or if you want to redirect inmediately use `_via_redirect` as suffix for the verb, example:

```
post_via_redirect :create, user: @user
```

Comment: This returns `undefined local variable or method 'post_via_redirect'` Am I doing something wrong? Where would you call this method?

Comment: Look into follow_redirect!, post_via_redirect is deprecated according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use integration/request tests. They are using web-like acces through routing to controllers. 
For example:
I have for Rails 2 app in file `/spec/integration/fps_spec.rb`

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 describe "FinPoradci" do 

   it "POST /fps.html with params" do
     fp_params={:accord_id => "FP99998", :under_acc => "OM001", :first_name => "Pavel", :last_name => "Novy"}
     fp_test=FinPoradce.new(fp_params)
     #after create follow redirection to show
     post_via_redirect "/fps", {:fp => fp_params}
     response.response_code.should == 200 # => :found ,  not 302 :created
     new_fp=assigns(:fp)
     new_fp.should_not be_empty
     new_fp.errors.should be_empty
     flash[:error].should be_empty
     flash[:notice].should_not be_empty
     response.should render_template(:show)
   end
 end
```

and it works. Until you want to send headers (for basic http authorization).

```
 env={'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,password)}
 post_via_redirect "/fps", {:fp => fp_params}, env
```

is fine for create, but after redirection it returns 401 and needs new authorization.
SO I have to split it in 2 tests: creation and show on result of creation.

Answer (score 0):

For RSpec / Capybara + Rails

```
response_headers['Location']
```

But it works only if there is no delay before redirect. 
If it is there, then it's harder to follow the logic.

Comment: this is undefined, but `response.headers['Location']` works