# Rspec does not seem to be targeting the correct controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Getting really bizarre rspec behavior in one of my controller specs.

It's best to illustrate.  In rubymine, when I set a breakpoint, this happens:

```
#rspec test
describe Api::V1::UsersController do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  describe "#show" do
    it "responds successfully" do
      get 'show', id: user.id
      response.should be_success
    end
end

#controller
class Api::V1::UsersController < AuthenticatedController
    def show # !!! RubyMine breakpoint will stop execution here !!!
      user = User.find(params[:id])
      user_hash = User.information(user, current_user)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: user_hash.to_json }
      end
end
```

So the above works as expected.

But, now this test fails.

```
#rspec test
describe UsersController do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, is_admin: false) }
  describe "#show" do
    it "redirects non-admin" do
      get 'index'
      response.should redirect_to user_path(user)
    end
end

#controller
class UsersController < AuthenticatedController
  def index # !!! Breakpoint is never hit !!!
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if current_user.is_admin
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @users }
      else
        redirect_to user_path(current_user) and return
      end
    end
end
By the way, this is the result:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/users/625> but was a redirect to <https://test.host/users>
```

None of my breakpoints in controller methods in UsersController are hit.  BUT all controller methods are hit if I set breakpoints in API::V1::UsersController.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.  I'm really at a loss of how to debug this.

Comment: Could you show the output of your log/test.log when you run the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this question was more out of frustation than anything.  But I finally figured out what was going on.  Hint:  `tail`ing the test.log is a good idea.

I was forcing ssl on the controller.  The request rspec sent is http.  `ActionController::ForceSSL` redirects the request to https and to the same controller#action.  However, at this point, the rspec test was finished and failed the test because it only sees the redirection back to the same controller#action.

So in a `before(:each)` or something similar, use this:  `request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'`.  All tests work as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you're stepping outside of the domain of rspec here with regards to redirect testing. May I suggest using capybara and rspec?

My sources: 
[Rspec - Rails - How to follow a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865378/rspec-rails-how-to-follow-a-redirect)
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33771089985/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara